# Resize rasters to add empty data around edges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a set of DEMs that have different extents due to different data being available at each of the sample points these DEMs were generated from.  I need to use these to create a set of uniformly sized rasters with the same spatial extents.  This would mean creating a new raster that has a null or 0 value everywhere except when it can use a value from the original (which is smaller).  I've played with `con` but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Another way I've tried to approach this is to create the larger raster at the resolution I want, then use the raster calculator to go through and set values when it can extract them from the smaller original raster, leaving them blank/0/null otherwise.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to implement that because I don't know how to refer to whether you're outside the extent of a raster or not.  Please let me know if I need to reword part of this to be more clear.

Comment: Mosaic all to new raster using environment extent = union of inputs. Set extent equal to one of mosaic. Set cell size. Use raster calculator on each of sibling, e.g. "rast1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so much simpler than I was trying to make it.  I made a shapefile with a square the size that I want all the rasters to be.  Then I just went into the properties of all the different sized rasters and set their extent to the shapefile that defined the new extent I wanted them all to use.  Set the extent of the data frame to the same, and then exporting worked properly to give me the correct extents (though this does not update their visible size without doing a reclass to put values in the added areas).